# MS Project Macro won't execute except from "view macros" menu

Tags: vba, microsoft-project

So I have a macro that has no errors. If I go to visual basic and hit F5 or F8 it will run. If I go to the View Macros menu and choose it, it will run.

However, if I set a keyboard shortcut, place it in the quick access toolbar, or add it to the ribbon, none of those do anything.

This is MS Project 2010 Professional. [image: Version info].[image: System info.]

Additional information: I created a new macro from scratch and it has the exact same symptom. It seems to be an issue with the program, not the macro itself.

Comment: Where is the code located? In the global.mpt, a public module, or a private module? How is the procedure declared? Is it a public or private sub? FWIW I can't get keyboard shortcuts to work on Project 2013 Pro, but the fact that it won't run from the quick access toolbar is an issue.

Comment: It's a module in Global.mpt. THe procedure is declared as a public sub (sub Macro1).

Comment: Have you checked your Trust Center settings (from the Project Options box)? And just to be sure, can you put a breakpoint on the first line of code to make sure the sub is not being called when launched from the quick access toolbar?

Comment: Yes i used a breakpoint. Also I tried with debug.print "hello" as the first line. Doesn't get called. I set trust center to run all macros, still did not run.

Comment: I found a few other posts with this issue, but no solution. Here are some things to try: 1) Check Disabled Items (Options: Add-Ins). 2) Reboot. 3) Try on another machine. 4) Close Project, rename global.mpt to set it aside, and start with a fresh global file (in case it got corrupted).

Comment: Only trying on another machine works. The others all failed. I need it to work on this machine though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72300/discussion-between-rachel-hettinger-and-the-ttg-guy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the configuration of my windows profile with the corporate network here. Within project, there are 2 copies of my global template showing, one was "Global.MPT" the other was "Global (+ non-cached enterprise". Moving my macros into the second was resolved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Export your module, open it in Notepad or Notepad++. Scroll to the definition for your macro procedure; there should be an `Attribute` instruction or two on the first lines of the body of your macro:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
Attribute DoSomething.VB_Description = "Does something"
Attribute DoSomething.VB_ProcData.VB_Invoke_Func = "A\n14"
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```

Here `\n14` stands for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> key combination, so this `DoSomething` macro is assigned to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

If the `VB_ProcData` attribute isn't there, add it. Note that the syntax for member attributes requires the member name to qualify the attribute (i.e. procedure name is `DoSomething`, so the attribute instruction goes `DoSomething.VB_ProcData...`).

Then save the file, go back to your VBA project, remove the module, and import the modified file.

Comment: Done. No change.

Comment: @TheTTGGuy I don't have MS-Project readily available, but I'll fire up a VM when I get home tonight. The attribute should be host-agnostic (tested this in Excel), but a given host has all rights to ignore them. Is there a *Macros* window with an *Options* button? Does this *Options* button bring up a little dialog where you can enter a shortcut key (and a description)?

Comment: Yes. When I add a shortcut key, the shortcut key does nothing.

Comment: Ok. That dialog's job is to write these hidden `Attribute` values in the module. Presumably if it's there, then shortcut keys *should* be honoured by the host app. Is there anything on *Microsoft User Voice* about it?

Comment: I thought that was only for Office 365. This is Project 2010. In any case, Google turned up nothing.

Comment: @TheTTGGuy I'll see if I can spin up a VM with Project 2010 when I get home tonight.

Answer (score -1):

I found this problem when adding a Macro to a quicklink in MSP Pro 2016.

The macro was recorded rather than coded directly and creating a new Macro (e.g. the `DoSomething()` example in Mathieu's answer) worked.

Copying the macro code into Notepad, deleting the original macro and creating a new version by pasting or typing the text in worked.

```
Sub Baselining()

    baselineSave All:=True, Copy:=0, Into:=0
    baselineSave All:=True, Copy:=0, Into:=14

End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried this already, with no effect. Sorry.